# IOException while copying file to hdfs

Tags: high-availability

I have setup Hadoop Namenode HA having two Namenodes. Two datanodes are also attached to provide data redundency(replication_factor=2). After copying few files, all files are failing to copy to hdfs. I checked the namenode logs and below are the errors

```
2017-05-31 11:38:16,034 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 2 to reach 2 (unavailableStorages=[], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) For more information, please enable DEBUG log level on org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy
2017-05-31 11:38:16,035 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.BlockStoragePolicy: Failed to place enough replicas: expected size is 2 but only 0 storage types can be selected (replication=2, selected=[], unavailable=[DISK], removed=[DISK, DISK], policy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]})
2017-05-31 11:38:16,035 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 2 to reach 2 (unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) All required storage types are unavailable:  unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}
2017-05-31 11:38:16,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 6 on 8020, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.addBlock from 192.168.9.170:49342 Call#5 Retry#0
java.io.IOException: File /delete_dir.sh._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 2 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)
```

Both the datanodes are working fine as i have checked them running.

I am very new to hadoop. Please help.

Comment: Make sure that there is nothing restricting communication between the nodes in your cluster. When a write occurs the first DataNode opens what is known as a write pipe to the two other nodes it wants to write replicas to. If it cannot open this write pipe replication may fail.

Comment: @jedijs How to check if there is any communication error. Since there are no error logs for network comunication failure.

Comment: Check with nc between datanodes

Comment: I have checked that the two datanodes are connecting and both datanodes are also connected to namenodes

Comment: any idea why this error?